# How to get a GPU input to use in shader as a variable in Vulkan API?

Tags: linux, gpu, shader, vulkan

Data can be sent to GPU over HDMI, Display PORT, DVI, VGA others. I don't know what happens next, probably GPU decode it and send to CPU, or just send to CPU and it decode it. I suspect that GPU save data from inputs to it's memory before sending to CPU, so it can be accessed from the shader. Probably, in code it should be like a structure of variables in shader, that is pointed to the input data memory in the code section of a GPU memory.

Comment: You seem to describe a process known as video capture, but you mention Vulkan API which is, generally, addressing video rendering.

Comment: @RomanR. there are opensource shader compilers and they can be extended to provide a array of gpu inputs to the shaders. Vulkan API is probably needed to allocate input sections of GPU memory to use in the shaders, like output to displays.

Comment: I should try to write a shader in machine code in the GPU using CPU to access memory.

Answer (score 2):

You read the data on the CPU (to the extent that the CPU has access to any of it) and pass it to the GPU via the various means for the CPU to give data to the GPU. There is no mechanism for arbitrarily accessing feedback data from whatever display output mechanism is used to the GPU. That stuff happens behind the scenes and is primarily of value to the OS and drivers.

Comment: If that is done by the OS and drivers, then it can be done by the GPU.

Comment: @AlexJoel: That's not how GPUs work. That's certainly not how rendering APIs for GPUs work.